# Apollo UseMutation: TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, graphql, next.js, apollo-client

Error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Call Stack
MutationData.onMutationCompleted
```

Following Apollo Docs and just don't see where I went wrong. One of `useMutation` hooks variables are dependent on the initial `useQuery` hook. I have confirmed that the `data` from `useQuery` successfully returns data.

The `useMutation` should return a url that I need use in `router.push(dataU.url)` but the mutation won't work in the first place. Not sure if `router` tasks in absolute url or only relative url.

This is 3rd party GraphQL API so its not like a backend issue.

`createUser.js`

```js
import { gql } from "@apollo/client";

const CREATE_USER = gql`
  mutation($url: String!, $plan: String!) {
    createUser(name: $plan, returnUrl: $url) {
      url
    }
  }
`;

export default CREATE_USER;
```

`index.js`

```js
import { useQuery, useMutation } from "@apollo/client";
import Router, { useRouter } from "next/router";

import GET_USER from "./getUser";
import CREATE_USER from "./createUser";

const Index = () => {
  // 1. Initialize router
  const router = useRouter();
  
  // 2. useQuery Hook
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_USER);
  
  // 3. useMutation Hook
  const [
    createUser,
    {
      data: dataU,
      loading: loadingU,
      error: errorU,
    },
  ] = useMutation(CREATE_USER);

  if (loading || loadingU) return <div>Loading</div>;
  if (error || errorU) return <div>{error.message}</div>;
 
  const user = data.user;

  const handler = () => {
    createUser({
      variables: {
        url: `https://mywebsite.com/${user}`,
        plan: "Cool",
      },
    });
    router.push(dataU.url)
  };

  return (
    <Button onClick={handler}></Button>
  );
};

export default Index;
```

Comment: test mutation in postman - query can work, mutation usually requires auth ... no `await` or effect to access `dataU`

Comment: Yeah this GraphQL mutation only works through Shopify. I simplified the example. They have a GraphQL testing tool you can test, but you can’t make mutations. When I tested it was just access denied because it was different app. So I know the GraphQL mutation works. How do I implement `await` and should I? Apollo docs don’t show that

Comment: if in doubt ... `console.log(dataU)` instead of `router.push`?